# MVVM binding with DataTable & DataView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, ado.net

I have a WPF window with some textboxes, comboboxes and a grid using MVVM 
the comboboxes and grid are bound to DataTable and DataViews, only the selectedItem values are bound to the Model

As of now, using helper methods as follows

```
void GetSelected()
{
  if ( SelectedDataRowView != null )
    obj.prop1 = (int)(SelectedDataRowView.Row["field1"]);
  else
    obj.prop1 = defaultValue1;
  if ( SelectedDataRow1 != null )
     obj.prop2 = (double)(SelectedDataRow["field2"]);
  if ( SelectedDataRow2!= null )
     obj.prop3 = (string)(SelectedDataRow2["field3"]);
  ...
}

/// and

void ToSelected()
{
 if ( TryFindDataRow("field1", obj.prop1, dv1, out drv1 ) 
   SelectedDataRowView = drv1;
 else
   SelectedDataRowView = null ;
  ...
}
```

as you can see, its pretty ugly, wondering how to clean it up !!

FYI can,t use EF & get rid of DataTable/DataView for now - the db is non sql server

Comment: Have you looked at `BindingListCollectionView`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindinglistcollectionview.aspx

Comment: @jberger this is the non-MVVM portion :)

Comment: i'd look into making it MVVM then..

Comment: @jberger, that's what this question is about isn't it ?

Comment: you said "this is the non-MVVM portion", which I presumed "this portion isn't going to be MVVM", rather than "how can I make this MVVM?".  are you wondering how to make it MVVM?

Comment: @jberger, here is the question excert from above "as you can see, its pretty ugly, wondering how to clean it up !!" hope that clarifies it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can convert your DataTable / DataRows to POCO objects with proper interfaces and put them in ObservableCollection which are more MVVM friendly. You can write mappers to achieve this or use frameworks like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com). You can keep using what you do and just use a mapper layer to convert them back and forth.

Comment: not familiar with automapper, does it have any support for mapping datarow/datarowview to pocos ?

Comment: It mostly works with Conventions but you can tweak it to support your own conventions. You can even write the mapping part yourself, but that is mostly boilerplate code that AutoMapper can do for you if using reflection is acceptable. Check their documents and examples on the web.